# how to attachment multiple file using php with pear mail.php and mime.php?

Tags: php, html, email, pear, mime-mail

i can't attachment multiple file. If i attachment file more than a files, email send always 1 file attachment, but i attachment more than a file.

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    include('config.php');
    include_once('Mail.php');
    include_once('Mail/mime.php');
    $allowed_ext    = array('jpg','bmp','gif','png','jpeg');
    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
    $file_name      = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
    $file_ext       = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
    $file_size      = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];
    $file_tmp       = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $username       = $_POST['username'];
    $judul          = $_POST['judul'];
    $berita         = $_POST['berita'];
    $max_size       = 25*1024*1024;
    $tanggal_kirim  = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext) === true){
        if($file_size <= $max_size){
            $file_path = "foto/". $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$file_path");}
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO foto VALUES('', '$username', '$tanggal_kirim', '$judul', '$berita','0')");
    }
    $query = "SELECT email,password_email FROM users where username='$username'";
    $sql = mysql_query($query);
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

    $subject = $judul;
    $body = $berita;
    //mail($to, $subject, $body,$headers);
    //email tujuan
    $to = "babagusandrian@gmail.com";
    $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $port = "465";
    $from = $useremail = $data['email'];
    $password = $data['password_email'];

    $headers = array('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);

    $namafile[$i] = "$file_path/$file_name";
    $crlf = "\n";
    $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
    $mime->setTXTBody($body);
    $mime->addAttachment($namafile[$i],'image/jpg');

    $body = $mime->get();
    $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array('host' => $host,
            'port' => $port, 'auth' => true,
            'username' => $useremail, 'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
    if($mail){
        echo '<div class="ok">SUCCESS: Foto terkirim!</div>';
    }else{
        echo '<div class="error">ERROR: Foto gagal dikirim!</div>';
    }
    }
}
```

what's wrong with my code? please help me. give me resolve.... thanks you..... sry for my english, im from indonesia. so just litle speak english. sry....

Comment: you are sending inside the for loop, so one email per file. to send every file to the one email you need to rearrange the code so that the sending takes place after the loop which adds the the files using the addAttachment method

Comment: hmmm.... where do change for loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was resolved by my self. i can do it....

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['judul']) &&
    ($_POST['berita']) ) {
    include('config.php');
    include_once('Mail.php');
    include_once('Mail/mime.php');

    $username       = $_POST['username'];
    $judul          = $_POST['judul'];
    $berita         = $_POST['berita'];
    $tanggal_kirim  = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $query = "SELECT email,password_email FROM users where username='$username'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    list($useremail,$password) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    mysql_free_result($result);

    $from = $useremail;
    $subject = $judul;
    $body = $berita;

    $to = "babagusandrian@gmail.com";
    $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $port = "465";

    $crlf = "\n";
    $headers = array('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);

    $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
    $mime->setTXTBody($body);

    $arr_files = array();
    $file_path = "foto";
    $file_count = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['fileAttach']['name']); $i++) {
        $file_name = $_FILES['fileAttach']['name'][$i];
        if(!empty($file_name)) {
            $file_count++;
            $file_ext       = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
            $file_tmp       = $_FILES['fileAttach']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $file_target    = $file_path.'/'.$file_name.'';
            $file_type      ="image/*";
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_target);
            $arr_files[] = $file_target;
            $mime->addAttachment($file_target,"image/".$file_ext, $file_type);
        }
    }
    $body = $mime->get();
    $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array('host' => $host,
            'port' => $port, 'auth' => true,
            'username' => $useremail, 'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

    if($mail){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO foto VALUES('', '$username', '$tanggal_kirim', '$judul', '$berita','$file_count')");
        echo '<div class="ok">SUCCESS: Foto terkirim!</div>';
    }else{
        echo '<div class="error">ERROR: Foto gagal dikirim!</div>';
    }
    // sukses atopun gagal, tetap delete file
    foreach($arr_files as $namafile) { unlink($namafile); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i very quickly rearranged the code, no guarantees on this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    include ('config.php');
    include_once ('Mail.php');
    include_once ('Mail/mime.php');
    $allowed_ext = array('jpg','bmp','gif','png','jpeg');



    $query = "SELECT email,password_email FROM users where username='$username'";
    $sql = mysql_query($query);
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

    $subject = $judul;
    $body = $berita;
    //mail($to, $subject, $body,$headers);
    //email tujuan
    $to = "babagusandrian@gmail.com";
    $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $port = "465";
    $from = $useremail = $data['email'];
    $password = $data['password_email'];

    $headers = array('From'=>$from,'To'=>$to,'Subject'=>$subject);

    $namafile[$i] = "$file_path/$file_name";
    $crlf = "\n";
    $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
    $mime->setTXTBody($body);


    for($i = 0 ; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']) ; $i++){
        $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
        $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.',$file_name)));
        $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $judul = $_POST['judul'];
        $berita = $_POST['berita'];
        $max_size = 25*1024*1024;
        $tanggal_kirim = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        if(in_array($file_ext,$allowed_ext)===true){
            if($file_size<=$max_size){
                $file_path = "foto/".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$file_path");
            }
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO foto VALUES('', '$username', '$tanggal_kirim', '$judul', '$berita','0')");
        }

        $mime->addAttachment($namafile[$i],'image/jpg');


    }



    $body = $mime->get();
    $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',array('host'=>$host,'port'=>$port,'auth'=>true,'username'=>$useremail,'password'=>$password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to,$headers,$body);
    if($mail){
        echo '<div class="ok">SUCCESS: Foto terkirim!</div>';
    }else{
        echo '<div class="error">ERROR: Foto gagal dikirim!</div>';
    }


}
```